# Overriding object's default getter operator

Tags: javascript

Let's say I have the following object in my JS code:

```
var myData = {
  "someWeirdPrefix_name": "John Doe",
  "someWeirdPrefix_age": 24,
  ...
}
```

Is there a way to override the default getter operator (`.`)? As in, if I write `myData.name`, I would like to get `"John Doe"` (thanks to the override). Basically I want to override the method so that I can take the key given, add the weird prefix to the key and then get the value. I know the easy approach would be to just clean my actual data and remove the prefix, but that's not acceptable in my use case. Is this actually possible to do for every property (not just `name` and `age`)?

Comment: I removed references to JSON since there was none in the question.

Comment: `JSON` is `JavaScript object notation` so `JSON object` is `JavaScript object notation object`. It's rather called `JavaScript object`. Also, is there any particular reason to use `var`  in your example instead of modern error-free JavaScript?

Comment: This is what I was referring to. There was a mistake in the question that was fixed a few seconds before I added a comment.

Comment: Should the `myData` supports updates to it ? And if so should a new property added automatically receive the prefix in its name ? or is it once set and only used for getting values from it ? Finally, can it contain other objects as values ? and if so will those have the prefix as well ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Usually [Proxy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Proxy) is used for that

```js
const myData = {
  "someWeirdPrefix_name": "John Doe",
  "someWeirdPrefix_age": 24,
}

const newMyData = new Proxy(myData, {
  get(target, prop, receiver) {
    return target['someWeirdPrefix_' + prop];
  }
})

console.log(newMyData.name)
```

Comment: that's a nice start, but try `console.log("name" in newMyData, {...newMyData}, JSON.stringify(newMyData));` to see how broken `newMyData` is. You should also implement at least the following hooks `has`, `set` and `ownKeys` and depending on what OP wants to do with this object, maybe also `deleteProperty`, `defineProperty` and `getOwnPropertyDescriptor`.

Comment: Fine, but question was - **Is there a way to override the default getter operator (.)?**

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you create a [**`proxy`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Proxy) over the `data` object, and on the `get` handler, you can check if there is a `key` in `myData` including the dot notation key, if YES, get the value of that key.

```js
const myData = {
  "someWeirdPrefix_name": "John Doe",
  "someWeirdPrefix_age": 24,
}

const handler = {
   get(target, prop, receiver) {
    return target[Object.keys(target).find(key => key.includes(prop))]
  }
}

const proxy = new Proxy(myData, handler);

console.log(proxy.name)
```